# Setting style property in Javascript through Array creating an error

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html5-video, undefined

Getting error in the following code:

```
var attribute=["position","top","bottom","left","right","zIndex"],
            prop=["fixed","0","0","0","0","-2"];

        for(var i=0;i<attribute.length;i++)
            video.style.attribute[i]=prop[i];
```

Error displayed by the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined` .

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`video.style.attribute` tries to read a property called `attribute` which does not exist, so `attribute[0]` throws the observed error.

To set `video.style.position = "fixed"` you need to use `[]` notation in your loop:

```
video.style[attribute[i]] = prop[i];
```

i.e. `video.style["position"] = "fixed"`

Comment: Could you tell me more about the [ ] notation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets - It's the way to access a property of an object when that property name is in a variable, such as your `attribute[i]` list.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad way of organizing attributes and properties, actually relations in generel:

```
var attribute=["position","top","bottom","left","right","zIndex"],
            prop=["fixed","0","0","0","0","-2"];
```

It is very difficult to maintain and expand upon. You should associate key and value:

```
var data = {
     "position" : "fixed"
    ,"top" : "0"
    ,"bottom" : "0"
    ,"left" : "0"
    ,"right" : "0"
    ,"zIndex" : "-2"
}
```

You should then be able to set the properties using 1 line of code:

```
for(key in data) video.style[key] = data[key];
```

**Complete example:**

```
var data = {
     "position" : "fixed"
    ,"top" : "0"
    ,"bottom" : "0"
    ,"left" : "0"
    ,"right" : "0"
    ,"zIndex" : "-2"
}
for(key in data) video.style[key] = data[key];
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll start following this coding style.